# Updating a hit counter when an image is accessed in Django

Tags: django, django-middleware

I am working on doing some simple analytics on a Django webstite (v1.4.1). Seeing as this data will be gathered on pretty much every server request, I figured the right way to do this would be with a piece of custom middleware.

One important metric for the site is how often given images are accessed. Since each image is its own object, I thought about using [django-hitcount](https://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount), but figured that was unnecessary for what I was trying to do. If it proves easier, I may use it though.

The current conundrum I face is that I don't want to query the database and look for a given object for every HttpRequest that occurs. Instead, I would like to wait until a successful response (indicated by an HttpResponse.status of 200 or whatever), and then query the server and update a hit field for the corresponding image. The reason the only way to access the path of the image is in process_request, while the only way to access the status code is in process_response.

So, what do I do? Is it as simple as creating a class variable that can hold the path and then lookup the file once the response code of 200 is returned, or should I just use django-hitcount?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Set up a cron task to parse your Apache/Nginx/whatever access logs on a regular basis, perhaps with something like [pylogsparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylogsparser/0.2).

Answer (score 0):

You could use memcache to store the counters and then periodically persist them to the database. There are risks that memcache will evict the value before it's been persisted but this could be acceptable to you.

This article provides more information and highlights a risk arising when using hosted memcache with keys distributed over multiple servers. http://bjk5.com/post/36567537399/dangers-of-using-memcache-counters-for-a-b-tests